# Проблема с pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmessagebox

Узнал о статическом методе `warning` класса `QMessageBox`(*PyQt*). 
Но не понял как с ним работать. В гугле ничего стоящего не нашнл. Буду рад если вы приведете пример использования этого метода.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html
целая страница доки, ну да, ничего стоящего

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите описание/пример того что вы изучаете и еще раз расскажите что именно вам не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Статический, значит для его вызова нет необходимости предварительного создания объекта. маленький пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                 
    def __init__(self):                         
        super().__init__()
        
        QMessageBox.warning(self,"warning title","my warning text")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```